# Flatlist keyExtractor returns "TypeError: null is not an object" when data is null

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have the following React Native Flatlist:

```
<FlatList
            data={dataOnDevice}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <RowItem
                  id={item.id}
                  key={item.id}
                  text={`ID: ${item.id} Name: ${item.name} Group: ${item.group}`}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.pop();
                  }}
                  rightIcon={
                    <View style={styles.icon}>
                      <Entypo name="trash" size={20} color={colors.white} />
                    </View>
                  }
                />
              );
            }}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <RowSeparator />}
            ListFooterComponent={() => (
              <View style={{ paddingBottom: insets.bottom }} />
            )}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => listEmptyComponent()}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          />
```

This works fine when I have data in the list but when `dataOnDevice` is `null`, I get an error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'item.id.toString')
```

This has happened after a refactoring which causes `dataOnDevice` to be null. My understanding is that `ListEmptyComponent` should be able to handle that...

How can I prevent this error with the `keyExtractor`?

For now I found a way around this by adding:

```
keyExtractor={(item) => {              
  if (item !== "") {              
    item.id.toString();             
  }            
}}
```

But I'm open to any cleaner way of handling it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that ID is not null

in keyExtractor

```
  if (item?.id !== "") {
```

Through? You check if the value exists if it does not return false

This way you can know that you are approaching an existing value  and avoiding an abnormal shot

Read more about  [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Could you explain what the question mark does after item?

Comment: Hi @remyremy
Now I have explained